# Don't understand how security works for SQL Server and SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am really confused by security concept.

#### Confusion 1:

When I add a user to SSAS, it becomes "server administrator" right away, am I right? Their permissions can only be restricted via "role" later. Is there any way to add a "normal" user?

#### Confusion 2:

What is service account? Is it the account being created in window system? Many online SSAS demos choose service account for impersonation (data source). Who set service account password? As far as I remember when O installed SQL Server package on my PC, the only password O set was the password for "sa". I don't even know installation process also creates service account.

Comment: [What is a Windows Service Account?](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+a+Windows+Service+Account) (I'm feeling lucky) -> [Service Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts)

Comment: hi Larnu,thanks for the message. is there any built in tool in window to manage service accounts? for example, view, or change password ... etc

Comment: Questions about service accounts are better for [su] or [sf], depending on how you word it. For this, likely [su].